# Contribution Amount not displaying on Contact

Tags: contacts, contributions, display

I am on civi v5.25 with Wordpress v5.5.3. After adding manual off-line contributions (no credit card) each with a different financial type to a contact, none of the amounts display on the contact's contributions. I also recorded additional payments on a couple of the contributions, and still no amounts display. The contribution detail report does not show the amounts, only the number of contributions, and oddly it also shows the number of contributions beside the amount, as in: Amount $ (3). Similar result on the contribution summary report. I've reviewed the financial account and type config and cannot see anything obviously wrong. I am new to civi so this could be something simple. Thanks.[image][image]

[image: Contribution Dashboard, Contribution from Dashboard and Summary Report]

[image]

Comment: In Civi go to Support > Developer > API Explorer 4  In Entity select Contribution > In Action select Get > In Where select Contact ID then in the blank box after the = start typing the name of the contact and then select one that comes up. At the upper right click Execute. In the bottom right you will see the results of contributions for that contact. In the array look to see if Total Amount has a number. This is where I would start troubleshooting, we can take next steps after this.

Comment: Also, please add more details. Is this a new setup or has everything been working until you did a manual entry? Was this the first time doing a manual entry? Is this only for one contact or did it happen for several.

Comment: Welcome Rose (i deleted my comment after rereading your issue)

Comment: Thanks Iowa Boy. I followed your steps for troubleshooting and I can see numeric values with total_amount variable. This is true for other contacts where I add a manual contribution. This is a new installation and I am just testing it now. I do see aggregate amounts on the Contribution Dashboard graphs, the Recent Contribution Contacts are listed below the graphs, but with no figures in the Amount column. Thanks.

Comment: When running a Contribution Report, check your filer criteria. About #17 down on the Filter tab is "Contributions or Soft Credits". Do you have that on Contributions?  Also, what do you have for Sort and Grouping Tabs? I would start with None for both.

Comment: If you go to the Contact dashboard > Contribution tab, does it show the amount there?

Comment: I checked the filter and it was set as "equal to contributions only". I changed it to "both". The results are the same: no dollar amounts are listed on the resultant report only the quantity of contributions made. On my Contribution Dashboard I do not see a Contribution Tab.

Comment: Also, when I search for contributions using a dollar range, it appears to recognize the manual contributions I created and only selects the appropriate contacts and contributions. But it does not display the contribution amounts. So the dollar values are stored but not displaying.

Comment: Would you have some CSS that is set to display;none that is hiding it?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the report?

Comment: I posted the dashboard, and another image with the contributions expanded. I don't think I have settings to hide the amount, but I checked again Display Preferences, and my login credentials give me Administrator full access. Thanks.

Comment: can you access the db and confirm the amount value is there? can you use your browser inspector and just confirm the amount is not there but 'white on white'

Comment: I do not know how to access the DB. I am just getting access to our host site and starting to look around to understand the directories etc.

Comment: She did confirm that the DB has the amount via a search with API 4

Comment: To check if css is the problem, right click on the form where there the amount should be, then click on Inspect or Inspector. This will open a box likely across the bottom of your screen. To the rightside you will see all the css to go with the element you are inspecting. You need to look for display:none or the color to see if something is wreaking havoc with your reports.

Comment: I added a screen shot of the CSS results. Colour looks fine. Should I be concerned about the message in the Console window (lower right?). I appreciate your continued perseverance with this/me :)

Comment: Try turning off your plugins in Wordpress and then check to see if you see the amount. I would turn off all plugins (except Civi related) and check your reports. If this works and you have a lot of plugins, turn back on 1/2 the plugins and check how it impacts your reports (to help narrow down which plugin it is). Then you can turn on/of 1/2 at a time of the set that is impacting it until you get down to the culprit.

Comment: If the plugins do not work, try a default WP theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we were upgrading our civi software we learned that removing the values in the Monetary Value Display fixed the problem. It looks like petednz-fuzion was pointing me in the correct direction. After the software upgrade, the value shown in his screenshot below for Monetary Value Display (%!i) were automatically populated into my config, and this also worked.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: oh good to know it was helpful. you should accept your own answer if you can to help close this off

Answer (score 1):

This is not an Answer so i accept it will be down voted but can't add screenshots to a Comment.

Can you confirm if anyone has tweaked the settings at civicrm/admin/setting/localization?reset=1 in a way that may have messed up the currency/value?

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pete. I do not think so. I checked those again and we accept CAD ($) and the Monetary Display settings look correct: Amount = %c %a, and Value = %c in my.